# How to revoke role access for a user belonging to a group in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

For example: if user named `Henry123` belongs to group `h1234` i.e., LOGON\h1234\Henry123', we should revoke `db_datareader` role from `Henry123` user but shouldn't drop user from the `h1234` group.

What's the way to do it from SQL Server database?

I am new to SQL Server. Kindly provide a solution to this problem.

Comment: What part of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) did you get stuck on? Then we can try to explain it further. (Though I must admit, the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#b-add-or-remove-role-members) is quite clear in my opinion.)

Comment: Thank you for the documentation @Larnu. It's really helpful. Please let me know if the below statement works in my case.ALTER ROLE db_datareader DROP MEMBER Henry123; without dropping user from the group h1234.

Comment: What do you think it will do? Have you tried? Why do you think it would `DROP` the `ROLE` when the command doesn't look like the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on that?

Comment: For such simple tasks, the documentation should always be your first port of call. SQL Server's is very complete, and constantly being updating by Microsoft and the community (as the documentation is open source). A quick search of "[How to remove a user from a role SQL Server](https://www.google.com/search?How+to+remove+a+user+from+a+role+SQL+Server)" on your favourite Search Engine will very likely give you the documentation link I gave you too.

Comment: I think it will drop member from a role but not the role itself.

Answer (score 0):

If the role has been given to the group and you want to remove the privilege done by a role to a member of the group without removing this user from the group, you must use the DENY command.
In your case :

```
DENY SELECT TO Henry123;
```